# Render 2 lists in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have 2 tabs in my React Native application. First one renders female names, second renders male names. I have a component `<List names={[]} />` and I pass into it an array of names based on the active tab. Like that:

```
  render() {
    const gender = this.props.isFemaleTabActive ? 'female' : 'male';
    return <List names={this.props.names[gender]} />;
  }
```

`<List>` component uses [`SectionList`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist) to show these names, but every time when active tab is changing it causes a delay in showing data and highlighting an active tab.

But It works fine if I use [`react-loadable`](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable) and do it like that:

```
const FemaleNamesList = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('../components/List'),
  loading: () => <Text>Loading...</Text>
});

const MaleNamesList = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('../components/List'),
  loading: () => <Text>Loading...</Text>
});

render() {
    const gender = this.props.isFemaleTabActive ? 'female' : 'male';
    return isFemaleTabActive ? (
      <FemaleNamesList names={this.props.names[gender]} />
    ) : (
      <MaleNamesList names={this.props.names[gender]} />
    );
  }
```

Can you help me to understand why in that case it works fine and maybe there is any other ways to optimize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st method only updates data on existing/mounted component while 2nd entirely replaces 2 different components.

In first case component has to compare data to detect changes (optimize items rerendering) - it can be costly operation for bigger sets. When component is created as a new instance it's not checked.

Probably (didn't checked) similiar effect (speedup) can be achieved when `<List />` will be surrounded within different (dumb, just rendering children) components to fool react with different tree structure, sth like:

```
render() {
    const gender = this.props.isFemaleTabActive ? 'female' : 'male';
    return isFemaleTabActive ? (
      <DumbA><List names={this.props.names[gender]} /></DumbA>
    ) : (
      <DumbB><List names={this.props.names[gender]} /></DumbB>
    );
}
```

Probably the easiest way to force component exchange would be using `key` property:

```
render() {
  const gender = this.props.isFemaleTabActive ? 'female' : 'male';
  return <List key={gender} names={this.props.names[gender]} />;
}
```

Of course this is not any kind of optimization.